# Should I release NSURLConnection instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using `NSURLConnection` class to get some data over the internet,my app gets crashed at some point and i get an error indicates that I've double-freed an object ,

here's how I create an instance of `NSURLConnection` and how I release it:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];
```

I should release it when I'm  done using it, am I right? or it get released behind the scenes?

**EDIT**

Now I got this problem sorted out, simply I made the instance of `NSURLConnection` as an ivar and released it in dealloc, here's the code

header file:

```
// ....
NSURLConnection *connection;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;
```

implementation file :

```
// ...
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
// ...

-(void)dealloc{ 
    [connection release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

the problem is I was not releasing the old connection before assigning new one, this done by adding self before ivar.

Comment: Consider using ARC in your project, it will help with situations like this.

Comment: I always use to release it inside connectionDidFinish loading or connectionDidLoadWithError(Not sure about exact name but you must have got an idea)...as both of these method has argument with current connection you are using...

Comment: you mean no need to release it in dealloc method if i managed to release it both in didFinishLoading and didFinishWithErro ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will be released and deallocated immediately, as alloc/init and release are balanced.

So, no, this is not what you want.

please provide more code regarding `connection`. What are you doing with it.

Most likely you will want to have it written to a property and released in dealloc.

Please make sure, that you understand the [Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html). This is vital.

Answer (score 0):

If you're (obviously) not using ARC, you have two choices:

a) hold a reference to connection and release when appropriate

b) you can also release the connection in delegate methods - analyzer will give you warning if you do this

First option is usually easier to mantain, especially if you're using more than one connection in one object.

If this is a new project, consider using ARC (as Richard J. Ross III already mentioned).